# How YiiBooster boost my Yii application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions, yii-booster

I am going to develop website in Yii framework and I also want to use bootstrap on the front-end. Recently I found collection of widgets called YiiBooster. I know, that it is using Twitter bootstrap and that is giving the way to write the code in Yii (by using Yii widgets) which will be transformed into bootstrap (HTML, CSS, JavaScript). But developers of YiiBooster claim that

> it is giving your application a little boost

And this is the thing which I don't understand. How it will boost my application? And what if I want to use good old way to use bootstrap by using simple HTML classes and have Booster only for enhance speed of my application (to boost it), is it possible?

Comment: just walk through this tutorial http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/

Comment: YiiBooster does not speed up your site, it only helps to 'boost' your web development.